# Storing Sets from file c++

Tags: c++, matrix

Say I have a `.txt` file with the contents

```
5
0 1 
1 2 
2 4 
3 2
4 0
1 3
```

The first number being the number of sets in the file(NxN matrix). The rest being sets of a simple graph.

I'm wondering what the best way to store sets of data(represent points for a simple graph) from a file would be. Looking to create and display an adjacency matrix with this data.

eg:

```
0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
```

I want to pull these from the file, store them (somehow) that I am then able to compare them with each other for adjacency.

I want to be able to read the two numbers individually, so if I see the set `4 0` I know that 4 is adjacent to 0 and visa versa. I also want to be able to look through each set in the graph once per matrix row ( 4&0 are adjacent, what else is adjacent to 4 )

How would you store this data to best fit my need? Stack? Array? Vector?

Cheers

Comment: Very interesting. The chosen answer has almost nothing in common with how I read this question.

Comment: Feel free to add your answer. @user4581301

Comment: @Jarvis not sure if it's worth the time. Could be I read the question wrong or the question wording is odd. I think something along the lines of `std::map<unsigned, std::vector<unsigned>>` better fits the "I also want to be able to look through each set in the graph once per matrix row" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing the pair of vertices, you can use [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) :

```
vector<pair<int, int> > vertices;
while(cin >> a >> b){
    vertices.push_back(make_pair(a, b));
}
```

Once you have the vertices stored in a vector of pairs, you can use a `2-d matrix` to store the adjacency lists. If one of the pairs is `(1,2)`, then you initialize the matrix at indices `(1,2)` as well as `(2,1)` (since the graph seems to be undirected) to be 1, indicating that they have a common edge, else initialize that index to be 0.

```
int **adjacency = new int *[n];
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    adjacency = new int[n];
memset(adjacency, 0, sizeof(adjacency));
vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = vertices.begin();
while(it != vertices.end()){
    adjacency[it -> first][it -> second] = 1;
    adjacency[it -> second][it -> first] = 1;
}
```

Comment: tactical note: the array of arrays approach can be painfully slow on a modern processor due to the low spatial locality of the arrays. Plus it's a bit harder to clean up. If you need this matrix to be fast, [build your matrix around a 1D array somewhat like this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)

Answer (score 1):

Ah what the heck. With

```
std::map<unsigned, std::vector<unsigned>> sparse;
```

`sparse` is a mapping of a node number to a list of adjacent nodes. I've gone with `unsigned` because most array-based matrices hate negative indexes. It's not an issue with this layout, but the point seems to be to build an adjacency matrix for high-speed look-up. This structure is smaller, assuming a sparse matrix, but it is sloooooooow compared to an array of boolean values. If you have enough RAM, use it. That's what it's for.

```
unsigned a,b;
while(in >> a >> b)
{
    sparse[a].push_back(b);
    sparse[b].push_back(a);
}
```

`a` and `b` are adjacent, so they get added to each other's row. `sparse[nodeNum]` returns a reference to `nodeNum`'s vector, so there's your list of adjacent nodes. For example:

```
std::cout << "4 is adjacent to ";
for(unsigned val: sparse[4])
{
    std::cout << val << " ";
}
```

Will print out all of 4's neighbour nodes, 2 and 0 in the OP's example.

Now that you've read everything in, you can easily determine the dimensions (if you didn't already by recording the largest number seen while reading the file) allocate the matrix, and load it from the poor-man's sparse matrix described above.